# Can't figure out why regex is not workng

Tags: c++, regex

I'm using a c++ regex for matching a string which begins with two words separated by a space and a newline, and containing more text with several new line characters. Something like this:

```
word1 word2
some
other
text
```

I'm using the following regex:

```
wregex rCompound( L"^[а-я-]+ [а-я-]+[\\r\\n](.|\\s)*?" );
```

`a` and `я` are the first and the last lower case letters of the Russian alphabet.

When the match is checked on the following string:

> wstring _s( L"а вот\n\
>   частица разг.\n\
>   1) Употр.при
>   указании на лицо, предмет, находящиеся поблизости.\n\
>   2)
>   Употр.при указании на последующий исчерпывающий ответ.\n\
>   3)
>   Употр.при усилении предикативной части при ответе на вопрос.\n\
>  
>   4) Употр.при сопоставлении с содержанием предшествующего
>   предложения.\n\
>   5) Употр.при противопоставлении частей сложного
>   предложения.\n\
>   6) Употр.при переходе к другой мысли, к другой
>   теме разговора." );

The stack overflow happens. But when the match is checked on the same string, but with the part related to the "3)" removed - the regex works OK:

> wstring _s( L"а вот\n\
>   частица разг.\n\
>   1) Употр.при
>   указании на лицо, предмет, находящиеся поблизости.\n\
>   2)
>   Употр.при указании на последующий исчерпывающий ответ.\n\
>  
>   4) Употр.при сопоставлении с содержанием предшествующего
>   предложения.\n\
>   5) Употр.при противопоставлении частей сложного
>   предложения.\n\
>   6) Употр.при переходе к другой мысли, к другой
>   теме разговора." );

The c++ regex implementation is of VS 2013. What can be wrong here?

UPDATE:

The match checking code:

```
bool _b = regex_match( _s, rCompound );
```

UPDATE 2:

Below is a code with a test project:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wregex rCompound( L"^[а-я-]+ [а-я-]+[\\r\\n](.|\\s)*?" );

    wstring _s( L"а вот\n\
  частица разг.\n\
  1) Употр.при указании на лицо, предмет, находящиеся поблизости.\n\
  2) Употр.при указании на последующий исчерпывающий ответ.\n\
  3) Употр.при усилении предикативной части при ответе на вопрос.\n\
  4) Употр.при сопоставлении с содержанием предшествующего предложения.\n\
  5) Употр.при противопоставлении частей сложного предложения.\n\
  6) Употр.при переходе к другой мысли, к другой теме разговора." );

    bool _b = regex_match( _s, rCompound );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this also happen without Russian characters?

Comment: can you show us the code of the matching checking please ?

Comment: @Cristophe - I added the code to the question.

Comment: @rubenvb - well, the regex is for parsing specifically russian text. The point is that this regex works OK with one piece of text and doesn't work with a similar one.

Comment: I ran this minimal code with MSVC13 with absolutely no problem, even with 3).  Is there no ther code that could eventually interfere ?

Comment: @Christophe - on my machine this doesn't work even in an empty new console project. (I updated the question with the full code.)

Comment: Ooops !  I ran it successfully in release mode.  But when switching to Debug,  I got the same problem as you.  Look like a bug !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this particular issue by rewording the regex as follows:

```
wregex rCompound( L"^[а-я-]+ [а-я-]+[\\r\\n]*[[:cntrl:][:graph:][:space:]]*?" );
```

I'm unsure however if this problem is caused by incorrect regex syntax or is this a bug in the regex implementation...